# Программирование простого синтезатора - частота звучания двух нот

Tags: аудио, музыка

Попробую описать проблему.
Каждая нота имеет свою частоту, к примеру, нота ДО равна 261,63Hz  в первой октаве, а соль 392,00Hz. 
Это значение используется после в коде для генерации звука по методу, описанному здесь:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731075).

Проблема: если я хочу сыграть две ноты сразу, как посчитать значение частоты? Это будет сумма значений или разность, или что?

P.S. В музыке я ноль.

Comment: любопытный вопрос, правда смогут ли на него ответить программисты?

Comment: Странное мнение о программистах :( ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Будут две частоты одновременно, если грубо. На самом деле будет основной тон + обертоны одной ноты и то же самое второй; на практике это означает банальную сумму сигналов, значение волны от источника А в данный момент плюс значение волны от источника Б, тоже в данный момент.